# Which profiler works with node 0.10.2 and will give me line-by-line timings?

Tags: node.js, profiling

Tried [dannycoates v8-profiler](https://github.com/dannycoates/v8-profiler) -- this one doesn't work with 0.10.2 and last update was 11 months ago, so it's fair to say that it's dead.

Tried [V8 Profiler](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/V8Profiler) and found that the output wasn't very good, lots of entries like:

```
line 288: unknown code state: undefined
line 292: unknown code state: undefined
line 293: unknown code state: undefined
line 295: unknown code state: undefined
line 296: unknown code state: undefined
line 299: unknown code state: undefined
line 300: unknown code state: undefined
line 301: unknown code state: undefined
```

and found that 87.2% of my ticks were in a library called `b7763000-b7764000` (or is that a list of function pointers?)... well that's not helpful.

I'm stress testing some code that is taking much longer than it seems like it should. I'd like to see what lines of code are taking up the most time.

Comment: The only difference here is that I have the name of the library as `/usr/lib/libc-2.17.so`. I filed a bug: https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-profiler/issues/11